# How to selectively apply JavaScript block based on profile in JHipster

Tags: jhipster

I try to include HeapAnalytics javascript block in index.html.

HeapAnalytics gives me two version of javascript block, one meant for development and one for production. It looks like this:

```
// dev
<script>xxxx</script>

// prod
<script>yyyy</script>
```

I want to know how to include the right one when I use "-Dspring.profiles.active=prod"?

Currently I do it manually, which is error prone.

Answer (score 0):

This information can be obtained in the http header, X-Application-Context, which is returned by the server. For example, the following were returned for prod and dev profiles, respectively:

```
X-Application-Context:application:prod:8080
```

or

```
X-Application-Context:application:dev:8080
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am checking if there's anyway, that change the tag in html for different profile, perhaps using grunt task?